# Why I'm getting two different answers when trying to figure out the probability of a single event?

Tags: probability

**Question:** Two cards are drawn at random with replacement from a deck of $52$ cards. What is the probability that none of the cards are kings?

**Approach $1$:**

Suppose, $P(A) = Probability \ of \ not \ getting \ a \ king \ card \ on \ the \ first \ draw$ 
and $P(B) = Probability \ of \ not \ getting \ a \ king \ card \ on \ the \ second \ draw$

So, $P(A\cap B) = P(A).P(B) =  \frac{48}{52}.\frac{48}{52} = \frac{144}{169}   \approx 0.85$

**Approach $2$:**

Suppose, $P(C) = Probability \ of \ getting \ a \ king \ card \ on \ the \ first \ draw$ 
and $P(D) = Probability \ of \ getting \ a \ king \ card \ on \ the \ second \ draw$

So, $P(C\cap D) = P(C).P(D) =  \frac{4}{52}.\frac{4}{52} = \frac{1}{169}$

Then, $Probability \ of \ not \ getting \ two \ kings = 1 \ - Probability \ of \ getting \ two \ kings = 1 - \frac{1}{169} = \frac{168}{169} \approx 0.99$

Could someone please explain why I'm getting two different answers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compliment of the event *None of the two cards is king* is

*Either* i) both cards are kings
*Or* ii) one of the cards is a king

So $P(A \cap B) = 1 - P(C\cup D)$

$P(C \cup D) = P(C) + P(D) - P(C \cap D)$

$ = \frac{4}{52} + \frac{4}{52} - \frac{4}{52} \cdot \frac{4}{52} = \frac{25}{169}$

Comment: Also notice that    
$ \small P(A) = 1 - P(C), P(B) = 1 - P(D)$

So, $ \small P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B) = (1 - P(C)) \cdot (1 - P(D))$

$ \small  = 1 - [P(C) + P(D) - P(C) P(D)]$

Answer (score 0):

Because "none of the cards is a king" is not the same as "not getting two kings". It is also possible to get just one king.